# Bottom Overflowed using SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xff003859),
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      "Conversor de moedas 360",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xff003859)
      )
    ),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xffffa300),
  ),
  body: FutureBuilder<Map>(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      switch(snapshot.connectionState){
        case ConnectionState.none:
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            "Carregando Dados...",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xffffa300),
              fontSize: 25.0
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          )
        );
        default:
        if (snapshot.hasError){
          return Center(
              child: Text(
                "Erro ao carregar dados...",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffffa300),
                    fontSize: 25.0
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )
          );  
        } else {
          dolar = snapshot.data["results"]["currencies"]["USD"]["buy"];
          euro = snapshot.data["results"]["currencies"]["EUR"]["buy"];
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(
              "images/360Tecnologia.jpg",
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Reais",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xffffa300),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        prefixText: "R\$ "
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffffa300),
                      fontSize: 25.0
                      )
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Dólares",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xffffa300),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        prefixText: "U\$ "
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffffa300),
                      fontSize: 25.0
                      )
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Euros",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xffffa300),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        prefixText: "€ "
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xffffa300),
                      fontSize: 25.0
                      )
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Libra",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xffffa300),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        prefixText: "£\$ "
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xffffa300),
                        fontSize: 25.0
                      )
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Bitcoin",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xffffa300),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        prefixText: "BTC "
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xffffa300),
                        fontSize: 25.0
                      )
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Bitcoin",
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xffffa300),
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            prefixText: "BTC "
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xffffa300),
                            fontSize: 25.0
                        )
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              )
            ],
          );
        }
      }
    }
  )
);
}
}
```

[image]

I want to show an image on top below the top bar. The image is fixed.

Below the top bar I have any text field inside the SingleChildScrollView widget, but this not work when I try to scroll the elements.

The text field can't rolling when I roll the screen to up or to down.

The stackoverflow want I type more text because I put many code, but my doubt is explained on text up...

Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Column(
   children: <Widget>[
```

replace that with:

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
```

You are seeing that error because your `SingleChildScrollView` is inside a `Column`.

Another solution is to wrap your Parent `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView` instead of second one. But that will scroll your image too.

Or, if your image is a fixed one, you can add that to `AppBar` `bottom`:

```
  AppBar(
    //...
    bottom: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(129.0),
      child: Image.asset(
        "images/360Tecnologia.jpg",
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Of course in this case if your `snapshot.hasError` or when connection is waiting, you will see this image(You can have a condition like `isDataAvailable` and make it `true` when connection state done and check it in `bottom`).

Another way is wrap parent `Column` with another `SingleChildScrollView` but that will make two scroll views. So to avoid image (Outher scroll view) to not to scroll add `scrollPysics: NeverScrollPhysics()`(But I dont recommend unnecessary wrap with extra widget).

Answer (score 26):

To address the `singleChildScrollView` issue, you can wrap that in an `Expanded` widget and that will solve that problem. Though, you may want to look into using a [SliverList](https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f) for what you're doing if you want the image to be up top and fixed in the app bar.

Comment: you are a savior. this works for Stack -> Expanded -> SingleChildScrollView -> Column -> etc